# Static files don't load in django login.html

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-static

My problem: static files in django can't load in my login.html. For example, it perfectly loads in my index.html, but not in login.html. I've tried everything: changing settings, urls, nothing works.
Here is the code for login.html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  </head>
  <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".site-navbar-target" data-offset="300">

  <div class="site-wrap">

    <div class="site-mobile-menu site-navbar-target">
      <div class="site-mobile-menu-header">
        <div class="site-mobile-menu-close mt-3">
          <span class="icon-close2 js-menu-toggle"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="site-mobile-menu-body"></div>
    </div>


    <header class="site-navbar py-4 js-sticky-header site-navbar-target" role="banner">

      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
          <div class="site-logo mr-auto w-25"><a href="index.html">LearnContact</a></div>
          <div class="ml-auto w-25">
            <nav class="site-navigation position-relative text-right" role="navigation">
              <ul class="site-menu main-menu site-menu-dark js-clone-nav mr-auto d-none d-lg-block m-0 p-0">
                <li class="cta"><a href="#contact-section" class="nav-link"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
            <a href="#" class="d-inline-block d-lg-none site-menu-toggle js-menu-toggle text-black float-right"><span class="icon-menu h3"></span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </header>

    <div class="intro-section" id="home-section">

      <div class="slide-1" style="background-image: url({% static 'images/hero_1.jpg' %});" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="col-lg-6 mb-4">
                  <h1  data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">Learn From The Expert</h1>
                  <p class="mb-4"  data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime ipsa nulla sed quis rerum amet natus quas necessitatibus.</p>
                  <p data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="300"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary py-3 px-5 btn-pill">Admission Now</a></p>

                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-5 ml-auto" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="500">
                  <form action="register" method="POST" class="form-box">
                      {% csrf_token %}
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="username"><br>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="password"><br>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-pill" value="Submit">
                      </div>
                  </form>
                  <div>
                    {% for message in messages %}
                    <h3>{{message}}</h3>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
    <div class="site-section courses-title" id="courses-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row mb-5 justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-lg-7 text-center" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="">
            <h2 class="section-title">Courses</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="site-section courses-entry-wrap"  data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="owl-carousel col-12 nonloop-block-14">

            <div class="course bg-white h-100 align-self-stretch">
              <figure class="m-0">
                <a href="course-single.html"><img src="{% static 'images/img_1.jpg' %}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid"></a>
              </figure>
              <div class="course-inner-text py-4 px-4">
                <span class="course-price">$20</span>
                <div class="meta"><span class="icon-clock-o"></span>4 Lessons / 12 week</div>
                <h3><a href="#">Study Law of Physics</a></h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ipsa nulla adipisicing elit. </p>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex border-top stats">
                <div class="py-3 px-4"><span class="icon-users"></span> 2,193 students</div>
                <div class="py-3 px-4 w-25 ml-auto border-left"><span class="icon-chat"></span> 2</div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="course bg-white h-100 align-self-stretch">
              <figure class="m-0">
                <a href="course-single.html"><img src="{% static 'images/img_2.jpg' %}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid"></a>
              </figure>
              <div class="course-inner-text py-4 px-4">
                <span class="course-price">$99</span>
                <div class="meta"><span class="icon-clock-o"></span>4 Lessons / 12 week</div>
                <h3><a href="#">Logo Design Course</a></h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ipsa nulla adipisicing elit. </p>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex border-top stats">
                <div class="py-3 px-4"><span class="icon-users"></span> 2,193 students</div>
                <div class="py-3 px-4 w-25 ml-auto border-left"><span class="icon-chat"></span> 2</div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="course bg-white h-100 align-self-stretch">
              <figure class="m-0">
                <a href="course-single.html"><img src="{% static 'images/img_3.jpg' %}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid"></a>
              </figure>
              <div class="course-inner-text py-4 px-4">
                <span class="course-price">$99</span>
                <div class="meta"><span class="icon-clock-o"></span>4 Lessons / 12 week</div>
                <h3><a href="#">JS Programming Language</a></h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ipsa nulla adipisicing elit. </p>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex border-top stats">
                <div class="py-3 px-4"><span class="icon-users"></span> 2,193 students</div>
                <div class="py-3 px-4 w-25 ml-auto border-left"><span class="icon-chat"></span> 2</div>
              </div>
            </div>



            <div class="course bg-white h-100 align-self-stretch">
              <figure class="m-0">
                <a href="course-single.html"><img src="{% static 'images/img_4.jpg' %}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid"></a>
              </figure>
              <div class="course-inner-text py-4 px-4">
                <span class="course-price">$20</span>
                <div class="meta"><span class="icon-clock-o"></span>4 Lessons / 12 week</div>
                <h3><a href="#">Study Law of Physics</a></h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ipsa nulla adipisicing elit. </p>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex border-top stats">
                <div class="py-3 px-4"><span class="icon-users"></span> 2,193 students</div>
                <div class="py-3 px-4 w-25 ml-auto border-left"><span class="icon-chat"></span> 2</div>
              </div>
            </div>



            <div class="d-flex align-items-center custom-icon-wrap">
              <span class="custom-icon-inner mr-3"><span class="icon icon-university"></span></span>
              <div><h3 class="m-0">150 Universities Worldwide</h3></div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-5 align-items-center">
          <div class="col-lg-7 mb-5" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">
            <img src="{% static 'images/undraw_teacher.svg' %}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 ml-auto" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200">
            <h2 class="text-black mb-4">Education is life</h2>
            <p class="mb-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem maxime nam porro possimus fugiat quo molestiae illo.</p>

            <div class="d-flex align-items-center custom-icon-wrap mb-3">
              <span class="custom-icon-inner mr-3"><span class="icon icon-graduation-cap"></span></span>
              <div><h3 class="m-0">22,931 Yearly Graduates</h3></div>
            </div>

            <div class="d-flex align-items-center custom-icon-wrap">
              <span class="custom-icon-inner mr-3"><span class="icon icon-university"></span></span>
              <div><h3 class="m-0">150 Universities Worldwide</h3></div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="site-section" id="teachers-section">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="row mb-5 justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-lg-7 mb-5 text-center"  data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="">
            <h2 class="section-title">Our Teachers</h2>
            <p class="mb-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam repellat aut neque! Doloribus sunt non aut reiciendis, vel recusandae obcaecati hic dicta repudiandae in quas quibusdam ullam, illum sed veniam!</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">
            <div class="teacher text-center">
              <img src="{% static 'images/person_1.jpg' %}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid w-50 rounded-circle mx-auto mb-4">
              <div class="py-2">
                <h3 class="text-black">Benjamin Stone</h3>
                <p class="position">Physics Teacher</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro eius suscipit delectus enim iusto tempora, adipisci at provident.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200">
            <div class="teacher text-center">
              <img src="{% static 'images/person_2.jpg' %}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid w-50 rounded-circle mx-auto mb-4">
              <div class="py-2">
                <h3 class="text-black">Katleen Stone</h3>
                <p class="position">Physics Teacher</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro eius suscipit delectus enim iusto tempora, adipisci at provident.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="300">
            <div class="teacher text-center">
              <img src="{% static 'images/person_3.jpg' %}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid w-50 rounded-circle mx-auto mb-4">
              <div class="py-2">
                <h3 class="text-black">Sadie White</h3>
                <p class="position">Physics Teacher</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro eius suscipit delectus enim iusto tempora, adipisci at provident.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="site-section bg-image overlay" style="background-image: url({% static 'images/hero_1.jpg' %});">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
          <div class="col-md-8 text-center testimony">
            <img src="{% static 'images/person_4.jpg' %}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid w-25 mb-4 rounded-circle">
            <h3 class="mb-4">Jerome Jensen</h3>
            <blockquote>
              <p>&ldquo; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum rem soluta sit eius necessitatibus voluptate excepturi beatae ad eveniet sapiente impedit quae modi quo provident odit molestias! Rem reprehenderit assumenda &rdquo;</p>
            </blockquote>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="site-section pb-0">

      <div class="future-blobs">
        <div class="blob_2">
          <img src="{% static 'images/blob_2.svg' %}" alt="Image">
        </div>
        <div class="blob_1">
          <img src="{% static 'images/blob_1.svg' %}" alt="Image">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row mb-5 justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="">
          <div class="col-lg-7 text-center">
            <h2 class="section-title">Why Choose Us</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 ml-auto align-self-start"  data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">

            <div class="p-4 rounded bg-white why-choose-us-box">

              <div class="d-flex align-items-center custom-icon-wrap custom-icon-light mb-3">
                <div class="mr-3"><span class="custom-icon-inner"><span class="icon icon-graduation-cap"></span></span></div>
                <div><h3 class="m-0">22,931 Yearly Graduates</h3></div>
              </div>

              <div class="d-flex align-items-center custom-icon-wrap custom-icon-light mb-3">
                <div class="mr-3"><span class="custom-icon-inner"><span class="icon icon-university"></span></span></div>
                <div><h3 class="m-0">150 Universities Worldwide</h3></div>
              </div>

              <div class="d-flex align-items-center custom-icon-wrap custom-icon-light mb-3">
                <div class="mr-3"><span class="custom-icon-inner"><span class="icon icon-graduation-cap"></span></span></div>
                <div><h3 class="m-0">Top Professionals in The World</h3></div>
              </div>

              <div class="d-flex align-items-center custom-icon-wrap custom-icon-light mb-3">
                <div class="mr-3"><span class="custom-icon-inner"><span class="icon icon-university"></span></span></div>
                <div><h3 class="m-0">Expand Your Knowledge</h3></div>
              </div>

              <div class="d-flex align-items-center custom-icon-wrap custom-icon-light mb-3">
                <div class="mr-3"><span class="custom-icon-inner"><span class="icon icon-graduation-cap"></span></span></div>
                <div><h3 class="m-0">Best Online Teaching Assistant Courses</h3></div>
              </div>

              <div class="d-flex align-items-center custom-icon-wrap custom-icon-light">
                <div class="mr-3"><span class="custom-icon-inner"><span class="icon icon-university"></span></span></div>
                <div><h3 class="m-0">Best Teachers</h3></div>
              </div>

            </div>


          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-7 align-self-end"  data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="200">
            <img src="{% static 'images/person_transparent.png' %}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>





    <div class="site-section bg-light" id="contact-section">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-md-7">





  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-ui.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/owl.carousel.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.stellar.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.countdown.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.easing.1.3.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/aos.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.fancybox.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.sticky.js' %}"></script>


  <script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for index.html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>LearnContact</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">


    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'fonts/icomoon/style.css' %}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/jquery-ui.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.carousel.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.theme.default.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.theme.default.min.css' %}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/jquery.fancybox.min.css' %}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-datepicker.css' %}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'fonts/flaticon/font/flaticon.css' %}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/aos.css' %}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">

  </head>
  <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".site-navbar-target" data-offset="300">

  <div class="site-wrap">

    <div class="site-mobile-menu site-navbar-target">
      <div class="site-mobile-menu-header">
        <div class="site-mobile-menu-close mt-3">
          <span class="icon-close2 js-menu-toggle"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="site-mobile-menu-body"></div>
    </div>


    <header class="site-navbar py-4 js-sticky-header site-navbar-target" role="banner">

      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
          <div class="site-logo mr-auto w-25"><a href="index.html">LearnContact</a></div>

          <div class="mx-auto text-center">
            <nav class="site-navigation position-relative text-right" role="navigation">
              <ul class="site-menu main-menu js-clone-nav mx-auto d-none d-lg-block  m-0 p-0">
                <li><a href="#home-section" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#courses-section" class="nav-link">Courses</a></li>
                <li><a href="#programs-section" class="nav-link">Programs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#teachers-section" class="nav-link">Teachers</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>

          <div class="ml-auto w-25">
            <nav class="site-navigation position-relative text-right" role="navigation">
              <ul class="site-menu main-menu site-menu-dark js-clone-nav mr-auto d-none d-lg-block m-0 p-0">
                <li class="cta"><a href="#contact-section" class="nav-link"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
            <a href="#" class="d-inline-block d-lg-none site-menu-toggle js-menu-toggle text-black float-right"><span class="icon-menu h3"></span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </header>

    <div class="intro-section" id="home-section">

      <div class="slide-1" style="background-image: url({% static 'images/hero_1.jpg' %});" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="col-lg-6 mb-4">
                  <h1  data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">Learn From The Expert</h1>
                  <p class="mb-4"  data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime ipsa nulla sed quis rerum amet natus quas necessitatibus.</p>
                  <p data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="300"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary py-3 px-5 btn-pill">Admission Now</a></p>

                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-5 ml-auto" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="500">
                  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                  <h1 style="color: white">Hello, {{user.first_name}}!</h1>
                  <p class="mb-4"  data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200">Make yourself at home</p>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-pill" href="accounts/logout">Logout</a>
                  </div>
                  {% else %}
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-pill" href="accounts/register">Sign Up</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-pill" href="accounts/login">Sign In</a>
                  </div>
                  {% endif %}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="site-section courses-title" id="courses-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row mb-5 justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-lg-7 text-center" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="">
            <h2 class="section-title">Courses</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="site-section courses-entry-wrap"  data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="owl-carousel col-12 nonloop-block-14">

            <div class="course bg-white h-100 align-self-stretch">
              <figure class="m-0">
                <a href="course-single.html"><img src="{% static 'images/img_1.jpg' %}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid"></a>
              </figure>
              <div class="course-inner-text py-4 px-4">
                <span class="course-price">$20</span>
                <div class="meta"><span class="icon-clock-o"></span>4 Lessons / 12 week</div>
                <h3><a href="#">Study Law of Physics</a></h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ipsa nulla adipisicing elit. </p>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex border-top stats">
                <div class="py-3 px-4"><span class="icon-users"></span> 2,193 students</div>
                <div class="py-3 px-4 w-25 ml-auto border-left"><span class="icon-chat"></span> 2</div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="course bg-white h-100 align-self-stretch">
              <figure class="m-0">
                <a href="course-single.html"><img src="{% static 'images/img_2.jpg' %}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid"></a>
              </figure>
              <div class="course-inner-text py-4 px-4">
                <span class="course-price">$99</span>
                <div class="meta"><span class="icon-clock-o"></span>4 Lessons / 12 week</div>
                <h3><a href="#">Logo Design Course</a></h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ipsa nulla adipisicing elit. </p>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex border-top stats">
                <div class="py-3 px-4"><span class="icon-users"></span> 2,193 students</div>
                <div class="py-3 px-4 w-25 ml-auto border-left"><span class="icon-chat"></span> 2</div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="course bg-white h-100 align-self-stretch">
              <figure class="m-0">
                <a href="course-single.html"><img src="{% static 'images/img_3.jpg' %}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid"></a>






  </div> <!-- .site-wrap -->

  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-ui.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/owl.carousel.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.stellar.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.countdown.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.easing.1.3.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/aos.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.fancybox.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.sticky.js' %}"></script>


  <script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here are the settings:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

I've cut some html, but not important parts, because Stack Overflow allows up to 30000 symbols only.
Sorry for my bad english!

Comment: you have to extend the css from index.html, {% extends 'index.html' %}

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines of code in your **login.html** in **head tag**

```
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'fonts/icomoon/style.css' %}">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/jquery-ui.css' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.carousel.min.css' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.theme.default.min.css' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.theme.default.min.css' %}">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/jquery.fancybox.min.css' %}">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-datepicker.css' %}">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'fonts/flaticon/font/flaticon.css' %}">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/aos.css' %}">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
```

Comment: OH! I accidentally cut it, it was very stupid question, thank you!!!